# Adding Enum as Room database column type

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a room database table and I want to have the column type as ENUM is that possible.

Enum

```
enum class Catagory {
    Insurance,
    MOT,
    Warranty
}
```

Room table

```
@Entity(tableName = "product_data_table")
data class Product(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_id")
    var id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_catagory")
    var catagory: Catagory,
}
```

This is the error message I get.

`A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution`

If I change the `catogory` type to `String` the error is gone, but I want it to be `Enum` type `Catagory`

How can I add Enum as the database column type please

Thanks
R

Comment: Create and register a class with `@TypeConverter` functions that convert your enum to and from some base type like `Int` or `String`.

Comment: can you give me an example of how that should be done please

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data#type-converters

Comment: that fixed it thank you very much.